# Dreamweaver + PhoneGap + Xcode App build nightmare

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cordova, dreamweaver

The issue is that I cannot now successfully build my Dreamweaver + PhoneGap App in Xcode for release in the iTunes App Store.

Background - I have been building an app using Dreamweaver and the built-in PhoneGap. To start with everything was working, including the emulator which started via Dreamweaver and the Xcode build. I have an early version of the app running on my iPhone right now with no problem.
After installing Lion on release, I started to encounter problems in that the App would not start in the emulator straight from Dreamweaver, but produced a fail message. However it did make an App bundle which could then be opened from Xcode itself. That was fine, but unfortunately now the App will not build or run at all in the emulator or my 'phone, which seems to stem from me doing a Clean in Xcode which I haven't done for a while. Very frustrating as it has been 3 months work and I was just about to release it on iTunes.I would be really grateful for ideas - the full buildlog.log is here http://bit.ly/tbYzVU

Answer (score 0):

You may notice in your build log the following error on Line 39, which appears many times in your log:

```
ERROR: The requested SDK ("4.3") is not installed.
```

The version of PhoneGap you're using in Dreamweaver is looking for the iOS 4.3 Simulator at:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk
```

However, when upgrading to Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion" and presumably [installing Xcode 4.2 from the AppStore](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12), you probably only have the **iOS 5 SDK**. From the Xcode release notes:

> **What's New in Version 4.2.1**
>
> Features and enhancements in previous Xcode updates:
>
> - Xcode 4.2 includes SDKs for Mac OS X 10.7 Lion and iOS 5.

To verify what SDKs (Software Developer Kits) you have on your computer, open the following directory in the Finder:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/
```

It's likely that all you need to do is adjust which SDK Dreamweaver is targeting when building or emulating your app.

In your situation, you'll want to change your Site/App's SDK from iOS 4 to iOS 5.

From the Dreamweaver Help section for Packaging Web Applications, refer to [Creating an Application Package (Mac OS)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WSeffff8bffc80208478c8d43312e240fe0ad-8000.html#WSeffff8bffc80208478c8d43312e240fe0ad-7ffd):

1. Select **Site > Mobile Applications > Configure Application Framework**
2. Confirm **iOS Developer Tools Path** is configured to `/Developer`
3. Select **Site > Mobile Applications > Application Settings**
4. Under **Select Target OS Version**, for "**iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad**, choose **5.0**
5. Build your App using **Site > Mobile Applications > Emulate and Build**

[image: Dreamweaver PhoneGap Application Framework]

[image: Dreamweaver PhoneGap Application Settings]